# How a regular expression is matched?

Tags: regex, string

Recently in an Interview, I was asked a question that I have a string with a couple of billions of characters in it. The string contains ASCII and non-ASCII characters in it. The task was to remove all the non-ASCII characters and in output, the string must contain only ASCII characters. The solution must be a time efficient algorithm.

I suggested two approaches:

1. Make an array of ASCII characters. Loop over string check if the current character is in ASCII characters array. If yes then skip or else replace that with null.

Obviously, it's not a time efficient solution.

2. Secondly, I suggested that if we partition the array in half and a further half and so on. I'll still be checking ASCII characters like in above approaches.

This conversation lead to a discussion where the interviewer was looking for a solution in which we don't have to go character by character and he suggested using Regular Expressions.

My Question here is when we match a pattern using Regular Expressions, will it check the string character by character or it'll use some other approach. I was sure the Regular Expressions will find/match character by character.
Can anyone please clear my doubt?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course it needs to inspect every character. How could you know if a character is ASCII or not without even reading the character? BTW, a string with a couple billion characters would consume GigaBytes of memory: you probably don't want to have such a String in memory. And an ASCII character is simply a character whose value is < 128.

Comment: @JBNizet, This is what I said. Any character having bit size < 128. But characters like new line, tab, carriage returns are also ASCII but they were supposed to be discarded. So that means we must go character by character right ?

Comment: "But characters like new line, tab, carriage returns are also ASCII but they were supposed to be discarded." That makes no sense, if the task is to keep all ASCII characters.

Comment: @Amadan, I think Interviewer was interested in printable ASCII characters. What "Peter Szabo" has correctly mentioned. I think I your answer is totally acceptable.

Comment: It is possible that the interviewer was interested if the interviewee understood Unicode.  If the string is UTF-8 encoded and mostly non-ascii, you won't need to inspect most bytes (not characters) to find the ascii in it (assuming you don't need to check that it is valid UTF-8).

Comment: @JimD. its an interesting point of view. Can you explain more? or perhaps point me in the right direction so that I can do reading.

Comment: Check out, *e.g.*, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) article on the UTF-8 encoding.  The first byte will tell you if it is ascii (1 byte) or if it is 2-4 bytes of an encoded character.  If, for example, you are processing a Chinese text, almost all Chinese characters are 3 bytes long, and since you can tell this from the first byte, you would have to look at only about 1/3 of the bytes to process a UTF-8 encoded Chinese text.  Note that there are other encodings for Chinese text that have nothing to do with Unicode, and other encodings of Unicode other than UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions indeed do use optimisations for cases where a sequence of characters is matched: simply explained, if you're looking for `"XXXXXXX"`, you know you can test every 7-th character, and only look closer once you find an `X` there. However, you need to filter every single character: this means, a regular expression would be not more efficient (and indeed it would be less efficient, because you would need to go in and out of regexp to process your discoveries).

Instead, the efficient method (assuming C-like architecture) would be to start with two indices (source and result) at zero, and process the string: if the character has the high-bit clear, it's ASCII: copy from source to result, increment both indices. If the high-bit is set, it's non-ASCII: just increment source index.

```
void removeNonAscii(char *str) {
  int s, r;
  for (s = 0, r = 0; str[s]; s++) {
    if (!(str[s] & 128)) {
      str[r++] = str[s];
    }
  }
  str[r] = 0;
}
```

(or you can make a non-destructive one, by copying into a new string instead of overwriting the current one; the algorithm is the same.)

Comment: And again to speed up we can use partition search type algos here right?

Comment: You can't, because you need to inspect every character.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a range like this:

```
[\x20-\x7E]
```

This range matches every character from [space] to ~. The printable ascii range.

Comment: defining a range or character set is not the problem here. Will this pattern inspect the whole string character by character or do we have a way where our program doesn't have to go character by character?

Comment: @SAM I'd say every character must be inspected, to check if they are within the defined range or not.

Comment: Yes I think you and Amadan both are correct in your approaches. Without reading value we cannot be sure of. thanks